# how to call two different fragment from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment Class 
and I have a linear layout clickable 
and a button clickable.

So I want to know that when I click linear layout it should start fragment 1
and when I click button it should start fragment 2

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.line1);
    l.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map_button);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Fragment frag = new Fragment1();
    FragmentTransaction ft  = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, frag);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();

    Fragment frag = new Fragment2();
    FragmentTransaction ft  = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, frag);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a onClickListener on your button and try that to show your fragment when it is clicked.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment1();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTr .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
    android.R.animator.fade_out);
    if (fragment.isHidden()) 
       fragmentTr.show(fragment);
}
```

Edit:

You can get which view is clicked with a switch case statement:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId()) {
         case R.id.Button:
            // show fragment x
         case R.id.LinearLayout:
            // show fragment y
      }
    }
```

Comment: With the FragmentTransaction. Look at my answer  `if (fragment.isHidden()) 
       fragmentTr.show(fragment);`

Answer (score 0):

your onClick method has to know what was clicked when you say setOnClickListener(this) you refer to the onClick method of the class .in your code it doesn't matter what the user clicks the whole onClick method will be executed . in order to specify the right block of code to be executed you can use Switch and case.